# How to get the memory size of an ArrayCollection in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, arraycollection

I have built an image cache which is an ArrayCollection containing images. I have built functionality so that the cache can hold a max of 250 images. However, the images can be of a different size, so it's better to limit the total memory size of all images in the ArrayCollection.

Does anyone know how I can get the total memory size of an ArrayCollection without looping through all the items in the ArrayCollection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can. My advice is to create a new collection class based on ArrayCollection (say, ImageCacheCollection) that keeps track of the collection's *current memory size* and its *memory limit*. Before you add an image to the collection you first verify that the *memory limit* won't be exceeded. If it isn't, you add the image to the collection, in the process adding the image's file size to the collection's *current memory size*.

Comment: With this kind of solution, I'm always a bit afraid that something might go wrong with counting and the counted cache size isn't accurate. But I implemented it anyway as there doesn't seem to be a better way, and I haven't had any problems yet. Thanks.